# How can I retrieve a JsonProperty using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I tried a google search didn't see any thing.. so maybe it's not possible?

my JSON class has a bunch of variables like this where the variable matches the jsonproperty:

```
    public class JSONChampData
    {
            [JsonProperty("banpercent")]
            public Banpercent Banpercent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Banpercent
    {
        [JsonProperty("evelynn")]
        public double Evelynn { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("zed")]
        public double Zed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nunu")]
        public double Nunu { get; set; }

        etc...
    }
```

I'm trying to come up with a way to say.. search for "evelynn" or "zed" for example.. and be able to pull up the value kept under "double Evenlynn" or "double Zed".. but I can't think of any other way outside of being able to look up JsonProperty elements..  is this possible?

I'm open to other solutions too.. I'm completely stuck . thanks

EDIT: full json file here: pastebin.com/9KWCCHk4

Comment: Why are you trying to access members by the attribute name? Couldn't you just use the variable name? To get to attribute data, you need to use reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to parse those particular values out of a JSON string? Are you trying to get the value passed to the `JsonProperty` attribute?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Could you provide some example input and output for an imaginary method that would do what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that let's say I have a string that has the value "evelynn"... I would be able to get the value of jsonfile.Banpercent.Evelynn.  I don't understand why everyone hates this question..

Comment: As I understand it, the OP is trying to map properties based on just part of the name -- to specify `"zed"` and have it map `{ "double zed": "..." }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your json.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);
```

---

```
public class RootClass
{
    public Dictionary<string,double> banpercent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> banpercentchosen { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> winpicks { get; set; }
    public int games { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> pickpercentchosen { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> losspicks { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> pickpercent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> banpicks { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> winpercent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> totpicks { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `JsonProperty` annotation is just saying that the json you deserialize into that class will have that property. I think you'd be better off desierailizing into a dictionary where the key is the champion name and value is the ban percent (`Dictionary<string, double>()`) but if you want to go this route you would just do;

```
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    Banpercent bans = serializer.Deserialize<Banpercent>(jsonReader);
```

Then to get say zed's ban percent you would do;

```
    double banRate = bans.Zed;
```

So the better route;

```
   Dictionary<string, double> bans = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, double>>(jsonReader);
```

And then you can do;

```
   foreach (string key in bans.Keys)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, bans[key]));
   } //writes all champ names and their ban rate
```

Also, that code with the JsonTextReader, could probably be a bit simpler. I based my sample off of code from an actual project I'm working on and it uses the reader thing for some more advanced options (schema validation), you can probably use some other overload that just takes the json as a string and get rid of that bit.

Comment: ah i like this idea.  will try this route and come back and see how it goes

Comment: i'm still having trouble with this.. i think because the Banpercent class is a subclass of another class... i edited the OP.. how would you go about using this dictionary technique?  i really like the idea, i'm just having trouble wrapping around how i can do it given my class format extracted from the JSON file unfortunately..

Comment: @user1189352 Where is your json btw.? Just post it don't make us  guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: sure sorry. here you go http://pastebin.com/9KWCCHk4